# How to write an installable python package for CLI based application

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface, software-design

I am working on a developers' friendly python based product. This python package is ready. Now we are planning to create it as a pip installable package so that developers can directly install it with `pip install <package_name>` and run it from command line with our defined set of command, e.g `$ <our_command> run`

I know how to publish a python package with `pip`. I need help to make it installable in a way so that without any further configuration user will be able to use it from the Command line (like `Rasa` or `pip` works).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+CLI and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+command+line+script

Comment: https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/

Comment: "*…make it installable in a way so that without any further configuration user will be able to use it from the Command line…*" That's actually impossible because users will have to add scripts directory to their `PATH`.

Comment: @phd Then how Rasa or PIP achieves that?

Comment: For some reason for some users it happens the directories are already in `PATH`. It's a happy accident, do not expect it will be always so for all users.